# MacOS open a new chrome instance without extensions or profile

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to open a clean instance of chrome without a user profile or extensions. I'm aware I can do this with:

`open -a "Google Chrome" --args --user-data-dir=/dev/null --disable-extensions`

However this won't work if I already have chrome open.

Is there a way to have my normal chrome open, and an additional clean one along side it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was simpler by just opening the guest profile from the top right of Chrome which achieved the same thing

Answer (score 4):

You can do this from `terminal.app`:

```sh
open --new -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-extensions
```

Take note of the **`--new`** part. This will ensure to open a new instance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to disable extensions for me. The new window it opens still has them all loaded

Comment: It works but you have to quit Chrome first